# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters (não encontrei resposta nos outros tópicos)

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, conexão

Sou nova nesse negocio de programação então estou meio presa nesse código, agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Aparece o seguinte aviso:

> **Warning:** mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadadmin\adm\conexao.php on line 3 Base não
>   encontrada

**O código:**

```
<?php
  $conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "tcc") or die ("Erro na 
  conexão");
  mysqli_select_db("tcc")or die ("Base não encontrada");
?>
```

Comment: No estilo procedural você deve fornecer o parâmetro `$link`, que no seu caso é `$conectar`, veja como fica: `mysqli_select_db($conectar, "tcc");` ... Para saber mais, leia a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php).

Comment: Eu consegui fazendo isso mesmo, um pouco antes de ver seu comentário. Mas muito obrigada mesmo assim!

Comment: Muito bem, como o problema foi resolvido eu abri votação para que a pergunta seja fechada por erro de digitação. Seja bem vinda a **comunidade**, se possível faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona as coisas por aqui.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigada